# I am trying to use NumPy and vectorization operations to make a section of code run faster

Tags: python, numpy, classification, vectorization, prediction

The below code takes long time. It will execute much faster if vectorize. Any help.

```py
def get_confidence_sets(y_pred,q_yhat):  
      
    conf_sets=[]
    
    for i in range(y_pred.shape[0]):
        a=np.where(np.cumsum(np.sort(y_pred[i])[::-1])>=q_yhat)[0][0]
               
        classes=[]
        
        for j in range(a+1):
            ind=np.where(y_pred==np.sort(y_pred[i])[::-1][j])[1][0]
            classes.append(ind)
        
        conf_sets.append(classes)
        
    return conf_sets

def get_class_coverage(true_label, conf_sets):
    d1=np.zeros(nb_class)
    d2=np.zeros(nb_class)

    for i in range(len(conf_sets)):
        d2[true_label[i]]+=1
        
        if y_val[i] in conf_sets[i]:
            d1[true_label[i]]+=1

   return d1, d2
```

For large number of rows it is taking long time in Google Colab with GPU.

Comment: Try to provide some sample input/output of the expected behaviour of your code to make it reproducible and easy to understand.

Comment: q_yhat = 0.99979335378

true_label = [7 8 5 ... 6 7 5]

y_pred = [[8.3482120e-04 5.5814441e-04 1.0471243e-03 ... 9.4656748e-01
  1.6802791e-05 4.1009677e-03]
 [1.2781517e-02 4.8641025e-04 2.5066312e-02 ... 2.8158069e-01
  3.3461573e-03 2.5813440e-03]
 [1.2102941e-02 2.1373389e-04 3.1547287e-01 ... 3.0181309e-02
  7.1551173e-04 2.8341456e-04]
 ...
]]

conf_sets = [[7, 5, 3], [8, 0], [7, 5, 3, 9, 4], [4, 2, 6], [8, 0, 1], .... ]]